# If $\mid f'(x^{\ast}) \mid <1 $ then $\mid f'(x) \mid <k<1 $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to show the following: let $ f $ be $C^1$ and let $\mid f'(x^{\ast}) \mid <1 $. Then there exist numbers $ k<1$ and $ \delta>0$ such that $\mid f'(x) \mid <k $ for all $x \in (x^{\ast}-\delta,x^{\ast}+\delta)$.

Here's my try: by continuity I know that for any $\varepsilon>0$ I can find a delta-neighborhood of $x^{\ast}$, call it $N_{\delta}(x^{\ast})$, such that if $x \in N_{\delta}(x^{\ast})$ then

$f'(x^{\ast})-\varepsilon< f'(x) <f'(x^{\ast})+\varepsilon$

Then I think I should choose $\varepsilon$ smaller than the distance between $1$ and $f'(x^{\ast})$ and I'm done, but I got a bit lost about how to formalize this last part. Any help appreciated!

Comment: There is a serious red herring in the problem. It boils down to the fact that if a continuous function is less than one at a point, it is less than one in a neighborhood of that point.


 If $g$ is such a function, then $x^* \in g^{-1}(-\infty,1)$ so that $x^*$ has a neighborhood $U$ with $U \subset g^{-1}(-\infty,1)$.

Comment: Not exactly: what I have to show is that if a cts function is less then one at a point, then it is less than a constant less than one in a neighborhood of that point. The existence of the constant less than one is crucial (this is part of a proof about convergence to a fixed point: I have to show that function $f $ is locally a contraction)

Comment: Sure, but if $g(x^*) < 1$ then $x^* \in g^{-1}(-\infty, k)$ for some $k < 1$ so... the *exact* same idea is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $|f'(x^{*})|<1$

Then there's exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $ |f'(x^{*}) | + \varepsilon = 1$

As $f'$ is a continuous function, then we have $lim_{x \to x^{*}}f'(x) = f'(x^{*})$

So, there's exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $x \in (x^{*}-\delta,x^{*}+\delta)$ then $|f'(x) - f'(x^{*})|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

Then $-\frac{\varepsilon}{2} < f'(x) - f'(x^{*}) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$

Thus $f'(x) < f'(x^{*}) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < f'(x^{*}) + \varepsilon = 1$

So if we take $k = f'(x^{*}) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, we are done